# Get file inode in Go

Tags: unix, go, inode

How can I get a file inode in Go?

I already can print it like this:

```
file := "/tmp/system.log"
fileinfo, _ := os.Stat(file)
fmt.Println(fileinfo.Sys())
fmt.Println(fileinfo)
```

Looking at Go implementation it was obvious looking for some `stat` method, but I still did not manage to find the structure definition for a Unix system.

How can I get the inode value directly?

Which file/s in the source code define the structure of `Sys()`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a type assertion to get the underlying `syscall.Stat_t` from the fileinfo like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    file := "/etc/passwd"
    fileinfo, _ := os.Stat(file)
    fmt.Printf("fileinfo.Sys() = %#v\n", fileinfo.Sys())
    fmt.Printf("fileinfo = %#v\n", fileinfo)
    stat, ok := fileinfo.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Printf("Not a syscall.Stat_t")
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("stat = %#v\n", stat)
    fmt.Printf("stat.Ino = %#v\n", stat.Ino)
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the error when you call os.Stat(file) above is not a good idea. Particularly when the file being searched for might not even be present. You can get a runtime panic if you dereference fileinfo without checking. I know it's just an example, but people might trip over this if they use the above model.

Comment: What does the line, `stat, ok := fileinfo.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t)` actually do? `fileinfo.Sys()` returns a *syscall.Stat_t according to `fmt.Printf("%T", fileinfo.Sys())` Some clarity will be very helpful

Comment: @Brettski: `fileinfo.Sys()` gets you an `interface{}` value—possibly `nil`—that captures whatever the `os.Stat()` call got from the underlying system call. The `stat, ok := fileinfo.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t)` line is a *type assertion* that says *I think what's in this interface value is a `*syscall.Stat_t`. If so, let me have it, and set the variable `ok` to `true`.* If `ok` is true, `stat` now has the pointer you expected (if !ok, `stat` is nil) and you can now use `stat.Ino` and other such fields.

Comment: @Brettski, to expand on what @torek said: Go must balance between two mutually-excusive requirements when it comes to interfacing with the OS: on the one hand the API it provides in its stdlib should strive to be 100% homogenous (cross-platform), and on the other hand, quite often a programmer needs to get their hold on the nitty-gritty platform-specific details. That's why `os.(*Fileinfo).Stat()` returns a value of "any type"—`interface{}`: the exact (dynamic) type of the returned value is OS-specific, and the programmer is required to _assert_ its real type to obtain a properly-typed value.

Comment: @Brettski, for instance, I beleive, on Windows `os.(*FileInfo).Sys()` returns `*syscall.Win32FileAttributeData`—you can read about it by running `$ GOOS=windows go doc syscall.Win32FileAttributeData`.

Answer (score 11):

You can do the following:

```
file := "/tmp/system.log"
var stat syscall.Stat_t
if err := syscall.Stat(file, &stat); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(stat.Ino)
```

Where `stat.Ino` is the inode you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Package syscall is now deprecated.  See https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys instead.

Comment: is there an example of how to use that package for this purpose?